# Intermittent piping failure in bash

Tags: bash

I have a code snippet that looks like this

```
    while grep "{{SECRETS}}" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile | grep -v "#"; do
      grep -n "{{SECRETS}}" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile | grep -v "#" | head -n1 | while read -r line ; do
        lineno=$(echo $line | cut -d':' -f1)
        spaces=$(sed "${lineno}!d" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile | awk -F'[^ \t]' '{print length($1)}')
        spaces=$((spaces-1))
        # Delete line that had {{SECRETS}}
        sed -i -e "${lineno}d" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile
        while IFS='' read -r secretline || [[ -n "$secretline" ]]; do
          newline=$(printf "%*s%s" $spaces "" "$secretline")
          sed -i "${lineno}i\ ${newline}" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile
          lineno=$((lineno+1))
        done < "/tmp/secrets.yaml"
      done
    done
```

in /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile, the string {{SECRETS}} appears twice 100% of the time.

Almost every single time, this completes fine. However, very infrequently,  the script errors on its second loop through the file. like so, according to set -x

```
...
IFS=
+ read -r secretline
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ read -r line
exit code 1
```

When it works, the set -x looks like this, and continues processesing the file correctly.

```
...
+ IFS=
+ read -r secretline
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ read -r line
+ grep '{{SECRETS}}' /tmp/kubernetes/deployment.yaml
+ grep -v '#'
```

I have no answer for how this can only happen occasionally, so I think there's something about bash piping's parallelism I don't understand. Is there something in `grep -n "{{SECRETS}}" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile | grep -v "#" | head -n1 | while read -r line ; do` that could lead to out-of-order execution somehow? Based on the error, it seems like it's trying to read a line, but can't because previous commands didn't work. But there's no indication of that in the set -x output.

Comment: `while grep "{{SECRETS}}" /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile | grep -v "#"; do` what does this do? Why is there a `grep` in a while loop condition?? `very infrequently` - for 90% you have a race condition. What does update  `/tmp/kubernetes/$basefile` ? What happens if it get's updated between the `while` condition and the `read -r line` statement?

Comment: The only thing updating /tmp/kubernetes/$basefile is this script. The while loop is saying while the string {{SECRETS}} is in the file and there's not a # in the line, loop.

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause of the problem is that the pipeline containing the inner loop both reads and writes the "basefile" at the same time.  See [How to make reading and writing the same file in the same pipeline always “fail”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409893/264812).

One way to fix the problem is do a full read of the file before trying to update it.  Try:

```
basepath=/tmp/kubernetes/$basefile
secretspath=/tmp/secrets.yaml

while
    line=$(grep -n "{{SECRETS}}" "$basepath" | grep -v "#" | head -n1)
    [[ -n $line ]]
do
    lineno=$(echo "$line" | cut -d':' -f1)
    spaces=$(sed "${lineno}!d" "$basepath" \
                | awk -F'[^ \t]' '{print length($1)}')
    spaces=$((spaces-1))
    # Delete line that had {{SECRETS}}
    sed -i -e "${lineno}d" "$basepath"
    while IFS='' read -r secretline || [[ -n "$secretline" ]]; do
        newline=$(printf "%*s%s" $spaces "" "$secretline")
        sed -i "${lineno}i\ ${newline}" "$basepath"
        lineno=$((lineno+1))
    done < "$secretspath"
done
```

(I introduced the variables `basepath` and `secretspath` to make the code easier to test.)

As an aside, it's also possible to do this with pure Bash code:

```
basepath=/tmp/kubernetes/$basefile
secretspath=/tmp/secrets.yaml

updated_lines=()
is_updated=0
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]] ; do
    if [[ $line == *'{{SECRETS}}'* && $line != *'#'* ]] ; then
        spaces=${line%%[^[:space:]]*}
        while IFS= read -r secretline || [[ -n $secretline ]]; do
            updated_lines+=( "${spaces}${secretline}" )
        done < "$secretspath"
        is_updated=1
    else
        updated_lines+=( "$line" )
    fi
done <"$basepath"

(( is_updated )) && printf '%s\n' "${updated_lines[@]}" >"$basepath"
```

- The whole updated file is stored in memory (in the `update_lines` array) but that shouldn't be a problem because any file that's too big to store in memory will almost certainly be too big to process line-by-line with Bash.  Bash is generally extremely slow.
- In this code `spaces` holds the actual space characters for indentation, not the number of them.